# Getting a slider value to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

My filtering system only lacks a price filtering. I needed a double slider for that, so I used [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/).

Now my knowledge of JavaScript is very limited, but I could figure out how to implement it correctly into my PHP file. Only I don't know how I can set the slider to a certain value and when the "Filter this" button is clicked, the value of the slider is converted to a php variable, that I can use. The easiest way I could think of was that the continuously updating value of the slider could be inserted as a `<input type="hidden">` element, where the value is the slider value.

```
<!-- the actual slider-->
<div id='slider-margin'></div>

<!-- the maximum value-->
<div id='SlidervalueMax'></div>

<!-- I thought of putting the variable from the script down below, that gets the values, into a input type-->
<input type="text" id="SlidervalueMin" value="">

<!-- the minimum value-->
<div id='SlidervalueMin'></div>

<!-- creating the slider and underneath that the value updater-->       
<script>
    var marginSlider = document.getElementById('slider-margin');

noUiSlider.create(marginSlider, {
start: [ <?php 
//I thought of keeping the value the same, when it is posted via the form above
if($_SESSION['Filter'] ==1){
    if($_SESSION['minimalvalue']!= 0){
        echo $_SESSION['minimalvalue'] ;
        }
        else{
            echo"0";
        }
}
else{
    echo"0";
}
?>
, 3000 ],
step: 100,
range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 5000
}
});
var marginMin = document.getElementById('SlidervalueMin'),
marginMax = document.getElementById('SlidervalueMax');

marginSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function ( values, handle ) {
if ( handle ) {
    marginMax.innerHTML = values[handle];
} else {
    marginMin.innerHTML = values[handle];
}
});

</script>
```

I've seen multiple similar threads of course. But because I don't know how JavaScript fully works I really want a personal solution to this problem.

Comment: I’m not sure, whether I understand the problem correctly. Do you want to set the initial values of the slider using PHP or do you want to submit the slider values to a PHP Script that stores it in the session?

Comment: @insertusernamehere I want to submit the slider value into a session variable. Which I can use to set the slider back to, when the page is reloaded, and to filter my products with

Comment: You can't get the min and max value in your JS code or you can't pass them to PHP?

Comment: @AlexYokisama I don't know to pass them to php. I'm unexperienced in JavaScript.

Comment: You mentioned, that you already have filtering, but without price-filter. How do you pass values for other filters? Do you use `<form>` or something else?

Comment: @AlexYokisama Yes I use a form. I thought of putting the value of the slider into a hidden input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to get the min (or max, if needed) value, you can do next:

Place this input inside your form. This input will not be visible, but will transfe data to your php script in the same way, as other inputs do.

```
<input type="number" name="Slider_Min" id="Slider_Min" value="" hidden>
<input type="number" name="Slider_Max" id="Slider_Max" value="" hidden>
```

Use this script to change values, when they are updated on the slider.

```
marginSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
  if (handle) {
    marginMax.innerHTML = values[handle];
    document.getElementById("Slider_Max").value = values[handle];
  } else {
    marginMin.innerHTML = values[handle];
    document.getElementById("Slider_Min").value = values[handle];
  }
});
```

Be sure, that all id's on the page are used only once. **ID's must be unique.** I've not work with noUIslider before, but I hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you very much! because of your script I was able to get the filter working.  This was the most relevant answer to me, because I did not need to change a lot of my code in order to add the values to my SQL string.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in a project once, was something like this:

- create two (hidden) inputs, that handle the values of *noUiSlider*
- set the values with the ones stored in the PHP session
- read the values using JavaScript and set the initial `start` values for *noUiSlider*
- create the slider
- on update of the slider, update the fields accordingly

This has the following advantages:

- the JavaScript is decoupled as much as possible from HTML and PHP
- you can have multiple of those sliders, just change the name that creates the relationship between the inputs and the actual slider
- the DOM elements are cached and don't need to be re-queried everytime `onupdate` is called, which could be a lot

---

```js
const sliderName = 'range';
const slider = document.querySelectorAll('[data-slider="' + sliderName +'"]')[0];
const sliderInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-slider-input="' + sliderName +'"]');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
  start: [
    sliderInputs[0].value,
    sliderInputs[1].value
  ],
  step: 100,
  range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 5000
  }
});

slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  sliderInputs[0].value = values[0];
  sliderInputs[1].value = values[1];
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/11.0.3/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/11.0.3/nouislider.min.js"></script>

<form style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <input type="text" name="" value="1000" data-slider-input="range">
  <input type="text" name="" value="4000" data-slider-input="range">
</form>

<div data-slider="range"></div>
```

---

Finally you can put the values from PHP into to actual form fields:

```
<input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['minValue'] ?>" data-slider-input="range">
<input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['maxValue'] ?>" data-slider-input="range">
```

---

**Demo on JSFiddle**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/rac6tky6/)

Comment: I think your comment was spot on, but it was a lot more work for me to implement this method and use it. For that I already had to work from a clean sheet, which I wasn't. But I think this answer is useful for others as well. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Well I already have most of the slider done, I only needed the conversion from JS to PHP. Your method is correct as well, but I'd have to redo my filter, which was too much work for me.